# Debug a function in R that returns NA

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function where it reads some pollution data from different files in a given directory, each file corresponding to records of a monitor and returns the mean value for one of the pollutants given as input argument to the function.

The data looks like this:

[image]

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, ID){
        pmean <- 0
        for (monitor in ID){
                filename <- paste("./W2/", directory,"/", monitor,'.csv', sep = "")
                print(filename)
                pollution <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
                class(pollution)
                head(pollution, n = 3)
                pmean <- pmean + mean(pollution$pollutant, na.rm = TRUE)
        }
        return(pmean)
}
```

To run the function I set:

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 110:112)
```

I am getting the following output and error message:

```
[1] "./W2/specdata/110.csv"
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(pollution$pollutant, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

My questions are:

1. How can I run the code line by line such that I see how the value of the local variables in the function changes? I looked up Youtube, but couldn't find a relevant video about it.
2. When I copy-paste and run each line of the code in the function in console I see that the data is stored properly in the pollution data.frame. why can't I see the class and the head of the data.frame printed as output in the console? Instead I only get NA which is related to pmean I guess...
3. How can I fix the error related to this error message?

Comment: Maybe the values in your data are read as a character and not NA values. That is why you could not handle them with the na.rm command. If this is the issue try to replace "NA" with NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. If you are using RStudio you can use the `browser()` command to freeze the program at a certain spot so you can view the environment.

Be warned that it will stop every time you hit `browser()` so you might need to put an if statement to detect a warning before running it. And don't forget to remove the statement once you're done.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, ID){
  pmean <- 0
  for (monitor in ID){
    filename <- paste("./W2/", directory,"/", monitor,'.csv', sep = "")
    print(filename)
    pollution <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    class(pollution)
    head(pollution, n = 3)
    pmean <- pmean + mean(pollution$pollutant, na.rm = TRUE)
    # Stop here and view the current environment
    browser()
  }
  return(pmean)
}
```